# I want to change my fields name in joomla

Tags: joomla3.0

i have created site based on joomla probem which are facing is that i want to change the name of field in user registration form 
C:\wamp\www\Joomla\components\com_users\views\profile\tmpl
but its not working..

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Changing ini files isn't the best way because You will lose those changes after an upgrade. Better way is to use Languages Overrides - great native Joomla feature.

You can find it in **Extensions -> Languages -> Overrides**.

Then choose New from top left menu and try to find your label typing it in search form "Search text you want to change".

Answer (score 0):

If you visit Joomla->language->en-GB you will find language files corresponding to each component, modules, plugins with extension ini. YOu have to select the user language file:

1. en-GB.com_users

**If you are using Profile plugin:**

Visit Joomla->administrator->language->en-GB you will find two language files with extension ini

1. en-GB.plg_user_profile.sys.ini
2. en-GB.plg_user_profile.ini

You will find the computer code on left and user understandable language on the right enclosed with inverted commas.

You need to change this language files to suit your requirements.